# Installing Autobahn twisted onto python 3.4

Tags: python, websocket, twisted, autobahn

I am running a simple server that connects to a https webpage through websockets.

To keep the server running, I was going to use asyncio.
To validate the SSL, I was going to use Twisted's rather simple functions.

My problem is I am having the worst time getting Twisted to run on Python 3.4.  Its static.py file keeps

```
    from twisted.web.static import File

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/twisted/web/static.py", line 440
    def _doSingleRangeRequest(self, request, (start, end)):
```

which tells me that it must be using Twisteds 2.7 code.

How do I go about repairing this or is this a lost cause?

Answer (score 1):

`twisted.web.static` hasn't been ported to Python 3 yet, according to [this open bug](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6177). You can see which modules are compatible [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3). Unless you're feeling really ambitious and want to try porting it yourself, you're probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

please check this

http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6177

twisted.web.static ought to work now.